# Check if user is using IE with compatibility mode

Tags: php, javascript, internet-explorer, dom, ie8-compatibility-mode

I am looking for some code (either PHP or JavaScript) would work well to check if a user viewing a page is using compatibility mode.

Then I can use that code to do some conditional statements, or basically give them a notification to turn it off.

Comment: related links on right not help?--->

Comment: You can use `document.documentMode` in javascript. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc196988%28VS.85%29.aspx for more details.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Force them to:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

This will disable Compatibility View, unless the user then goes and specifically turns it off by going into the Developer Tools and changing it.

Answer (score 0):

I use:

```
try{ JSON } catch (e){ alert("Compatibility Mode Detected")  }
```